# How do I keep a bottom div a constant height below a top div with a div between them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have three divs aligned vertically and want the middle div to fade in and out with javascript by animating the opacity and setting 'display: none;'. However when I do this it causes the bottom div to move down the page to make room for the middle div.

How can I make the bottom div a constant height below the top div independent of whether the middle div is displayed or not?

Comment: maybe use position absolute?

Comment: Please add some code, it will help your question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `visibility: hidden;` instead of `display: none;`

`visibility: hidden;` hides an element, but it will still take up the same space as before.